# Как распарсить JSON массив в Android

Tags: android, json, vkontakte-api

Как распарсить данный JSON массив? Первое кол-во постов, далее сами посты.
Нужны преобразовать его в JSONArray, получить количество элементов данного массива и распарсить их в цикле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь для начала вытащить количество элементов

```
try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(response));
                int count = jsonArray.length();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Я делал по примерам из этого вопроса. Не прокатило.

Comment: Значит вопрос надо задавать не "как распарсить", а "делал вот так и так, писал то и то, вот такой код, но в результате ошибка/не компилируется/взрывается мусоропровод"

Comment: Сможете пример набросать, если не сложно?

Comment: Вы видите мой второй комментарий? Либо вы делаете все по нему, либо вопрос закрывается как дубликат. Потому что примеры описаны в дубликате.

Comment: обновил вопрос. посмотрите

Comment: так, и что в этом нужно увидеть? нужно угадать какую ошибку выдает? откуда взялся `new JSONArray` ? его нет в примерах приведенного дубликата. Приведите json текстом для проверки, приведите описания ошибки и прочее. [Справка > Как задавать вопросы > как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вот в вашем ответе на тот вопрос, который скинули. Там в разделе Simple JSON есть кусок кода new JSONParser. У меня нет этого JSONParser. Это отдельная библиотека?

Comment: Это всё - отдельные библиотеки, да. Там специально ссылки указаны, указывающие, что надо библиотеки добавлять

Comment: Блин а через зависимости никак?

Comment: Где взять: здесь / репозиторий на github / **или через Maven и пр.**

Comment: А я вот к jsonArray не могу применить метод iterator(), почему? Он красный.

Comment: судя по response его нужно преобр-ть в JSONObject. попробуйте JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject(response); имею ввиду не поле "response": ... а всю строку с фигурными скобками

Comment: еще вопрос: как вы наверное уже поняли, это посты со стены группы вк, можно ли как-то убрать слэши и тэги разметки?